# Set default action for removable drive?

Tags: 18.04, usb, kubuntu

**Kubuntu 18.04 LTS.**

I use USB memory sticks a lot. When I plug in a stick I get a little popup asking me if I want to open Dolphin or download pictures with Gwenview. I will NEVER want to download pictures, but I can't find a place where I can set Dolphin to just open by default. Is there such a setting?

Comment: There may be something in System Settings for "Removable Storage" or something like that - don't know how it is called exactly on Kubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunately, that only allows for mounting devices. There's no place I can see that specifies opening it in an app, like Dolphin.